# Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.demo.User]

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm working on **Spring Boot and Apache Kafka** - trying to have a user defined configurations -

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.example.demo.Consumer.consume(com.example.demo.User) throws java.io.IOException]
Bean [com.example.demo.Consumer@7cd4a8cc]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.demo.User] for GenericMessage [payload={"name":"Prateek","age":33}, headers={kafka_offset=7, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@32375775, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=users, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613708323636, __TypeId__=[B@165438c, kafka_groupId=group_id}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"name":"Prateek","age":33}, headers={kafka_offset=7, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@32375775, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=users, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613708323636, __TypeId__=[B@165438c, kafka_groupId=group_id}]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.demo.User] for GenericMessage [payload={"name":"Prateek","age":33}, headers={kafka_offset=7, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@32375775, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=users, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613708323636, __TypeId__=[B@165438c, kafka_groupId=group_id}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"name":"Prateek","age":33}, headers={kafka_offset=7, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@32375775, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=users, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613708323636, __TypeId__=[B@165438c, kafka_groupId=group_id}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2110) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2098) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1997) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1924) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1812) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1531) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1075) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.demo.User] for GenericMessage [payload={"name":"Prateek","age":33}, headers={kafka_offset=7, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@32375775, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=users, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613708323636, __TypeId__=[B@165438c, kafka_groupId=group_id}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"name":"Prateek","age":33}, headers={kafka_offset=7, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@32375775, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=users, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613708323636, __TypeId__=[B@165438c, kafka_groupId=group_id}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:340) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2065) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2047) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1984) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [com.example.demo.User] for GenericMessage [payload={"name":"Prateek","age":33}, headers={kafka_offset=7, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@32375775, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=users, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613708323636, __TypeId__=[B@165438c, kafka_groupId=group_id}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java:145) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:926) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:329) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

How can we solve this?

Below is my code -

User.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

KafkaProducerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    // 1. Send string to Kafka
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    // 2. Send User objects to Kafka
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, User> userProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, User> userKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(userProducerFactory());
    }
}
```

Producer.java

```
@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "users";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(User user) {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Producing message -> %s", user.toString()));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, user);
    }
}
```

KafkaConsumerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${general.topic.group.id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Value(value = "${user.topic.group.id}")
    private String userGroupId;

    // 1. Consume string data from Kafka
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    // 2. Consume user objects from Kafka
    public ConsumerFactory<String, User> userConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, userGroupId);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(User.class));
    }
    

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> userKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(userConsumerFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Consumer.java

```
@Service
public class Consumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "users", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(User user) throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", user.toString()));
    }
}
```

KafkaController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/kafka")
public class KafkaController {

    private final Producer producer;

    @Autowired
    KafkaController(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/publish")
    public void sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestBody User user) {
        this.producer.sendMessage(user);
    }
}
```

KafkaExampleApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=9000

kafka.bootstrapAddress=localhost:9092
general.topic.group.id=group_id
user.topic.group.id=MyGrpId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this into your @KafkaListener annotation, like in second clause in @Lotzy answer:

```
containerFactory = userKafkaListenerContainerFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Producer class, you need to rename the `kafkaTemplate` to `userKafkaTemplate`, which is wired to the User producer factory with the JSON serializer you want to use.

In fact, you should probably remove the other template and producer factory if you're not using them

Comment: This does not solve the issue, and also variable name can be anything. The generic type is enough to recognize which bean to be wired by Spring boot.

Comment: @Sayan Yes it does. It's Autowired by name. "Spring uses the bean's name as a default qualifier value" https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire Feel free to provide your own answer if you have another solution

Comment: In that link : "By default, Spring resolves @Autowired entries by type". Does a qualifier not just help to distinguish between multiple beans of the same type? (which is not the case here)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the *KafkaConsumerConfig.java* configuration of bean *userConsumerFactory()* you are using userGroupId="**MyGrpId**" via @Value wiring from property user.topic.group.id=MyGrpId. But then in the Consumer.java at the @KafkaListener annotation, it is specified groupId = "**group_id**".
2. In the same annotation, would be better to specify the containerFactory instead of the groupId, like this `@KafkaListener(topics = "users", containerFactory = "userKafkaListenerContainerFactory")`. This way the annotation will wire exactly the wanted *ConsumerFactory* bean configuration via the *ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory*.
3. Also, I agree with @OneCricketeer, that in the Producer you should qualify the autowired kafkaTemplate to the one that produces User objects of you later want to consume JSON deserializable to User objects, like this:

   @Autowired

   @Qualifier("userKafkaTemplate")

   private KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

More details here: [Baeldung - Apache Kafka with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your properties to let deserializer know what to cast into

```
properties.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE,com.example.demo.User.class);
```